# angular 4 how to get url parameters

Tags: angular, typescript

Need help again!

I am using Angular 4 and would like to get the parameters from a url in my component. URL is "http://myhost/index?user=James&token=123&picture=3456abc.png" or "http://myhost/index?user=Peter"

I tried these varies methods, but without luck.

How can I get the url parameters 'user', 'token' and 'picture'?

```
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router, ActivatedRoute, RouteSegment, Params, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

  constructor(private restSvc: RestSvc, private router: Router, private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private mdIconRegistry: MdIconRegistry, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private routeSegment: RouteSegment) {

    // Method 1: subscribe to queryParamMap - not working - all values are undefined
    /*    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
          this.userName = params['user'];
          this.userToken = params['token'];
          this.userPicture = params['picture'];
        }) */

    // Method 2: use the $location service - not working
    //var params = $location.search('user', 'token', 'picture');  //syntax error - cannot find name $location

    // Method 3:  RouteSegment
    this.userName = routeSegment.getParam('user'); // Error:  compile eror - has no exported member 'RouteSegment'.    

    console.log("App Component Constructor - params user [" + this.userName + "]");
  }
```

--- Resolved -----------------------------

I have tried activatedRoute approach, but didn't work. At the end, I go back to the basic suggested by Rach. It works now. The url that I am trying to parse is not from route.navigate. It is a redirection from my server. Not sure it matter or not.

**Lesson learned: sometimes, it is good to go back to the basic, i.e. simply parsing the location.href string by & and = to get the parameters.**

Comment: How did you navigate the page?show the ` navigate code` and full url.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, set the `ActivatedRoute` in your `constructor`

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}
public user:your_type;
```

Secondly, put this code in constructor callback:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => { this.user = params['user']; });
```

This method will work if you use the following code to redirect:

```
this.router.navigate(['./yourlocation', { user: this.user }]);
```

### Modifed

Angular Url structure is `a/:paras1/:paras2` or `a?a=3;` without using `&`.

If you use `&` to separate your parameters, it is recommended to use nativeJS to get.

```
constructor(){
  this.user = this.getUrlParameter('user');
}

public user;
private getUrlParameter(sParam) {
  return decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)).split('&')
   .map((v) => { return v.split("=") })
   .filter((v) => { return (v[0] === sParam) ? true : false })
   .reduce((prev, curv, index, array) => { return curv[1]; }, undefined); 
};
```

Comment: Hi Rach, thx a lot! Would you please help to check your suggested code. I got syntax error on .reduce((prev, curv, index, array) => { return curv[1]; }, undefined);. Apologized that I couldn't fix it.

Comment: ERROR in /apps/fhir2_james/src/app/app.component.ts (46,15): Argument of type '(prev: string[], curv: string[], index: number, array: string[][]) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: string[], currentValue: string[], currentIndex: number, array: string[][]) => str...'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.

Comment: Hi Rach, you are right that "If you use & to separate your parameters , recommend to use nativeJS to get." It works now.

Comment: glad to hear that.

Comment: public getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    return decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)).split('&')
     .map((v) => { return v.split("=") })
     .filter((v) => { return (v[0] === sParam) ? true : false })
     .reduce((acc:any,curr:any) => { return curr[1]; },undefined);
  };

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use query params and not define them in route, you can reference ActivatedRoute in your constructor and subscribe to queryParams.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
          // here you can access params['user'], params['token'], etc.
      });
}
```

Comment: More read here: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/query_params.html

Comment: Thanks Vitali. this was my first method using queryParams to resolve my issue. However, for some reasons, it didn't work out.

Answer (score 2):

By using ActivatedRoute snapshot as below example.

```
this.userName = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['user'];
this.userToken = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['token'];
this.userPicture = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['picture'];
```

Comment: Hi, do I need to define that route because those user, token and picture are parameters only? I thought I just need to define site/index. The URL is "hxxp://myhost/index?user=James&token=123&picture=3456abc.png". Thx so .much for the help!

Comment: Hi i3lai3la, I tried your code, but still couldn't get the parameter. Will it because the url is a redirection from our server after the Facebook OAuth return? Hence, the url is not from Angular navigation and it is the first initial url of my Angular apps. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

**Want to know all url parameters?**

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
       console.log(params)
    })
}
```

**In child route, you need to use `parent` to get parent-route parameters**

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    console.log(params)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Double check to make sure you defined the routes properly.

In your route definition you should have something like this:

`path: ':user/:id/:token/:picture'`

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Would you please look at my comment to 'i3lai3la'. I didn't define the route as ':user/:id/:token/:picture'. I define my route as site/index only.

Answer (score 1):

To get url parameters in angular 4 eg:http://localhost/doctor?test=1

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.home.html',
})

export class HomeComponant {
title = 'Home';


constructor(

    private router: Router,

) {}

onSubmit() {
  this.router.navigate(['/doctor'],{queryParams:{test:1}});
}
```

}